# using ASIHTTPRequest in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

i m making a client server program for iphone.i am going  use ASIHTTPRequest for uploading the file to server by picking following code from stackoverflow .i want  to know that can i use it in a view based application and what should be imported for using ASIHTTPRequest.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addPostValue:token forKey:@"token"];
[request setFile:recorderFilePath forKey:@"thefile"];
[request startSynchronous];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to use ASIFormDataRequest, you need corresponding files,

you can find those files here:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

To know how to use check:
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Comment: Agree, the documentation and files at the ASIHTTPRequest site provide everything you need.